# How can I make this work - client already declared

Tags: javascript

CODE:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { token } = process.env;
const {client, collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
client.commands = new collection();
client.commandArray = [];

const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
  const functionFiles = fs
    .readdirSync('./src/functions/${folder}')
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of functionFiles)
    require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
}

client.handleEvents();
client.handleCommands();
client.login(token);
```

ERROR after running npm run test:

```
**const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
      ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'client' has already been declared**
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I have tried deleting line 3 as Client is already handled at line 6 but that throws a different error also.

Can someone please advise?

I have tried deleting line 3 as Client is already handled at line 6 but that throws a different error also.

Tried removing "client" from line 3

Comment: What error do you get when you remove just client from line 3?

Comment: const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
               ^

ReferenceError: Client is not defined

Comment: It should probably be `Client` not `client` in your import/require

Comment: Same goes for `Collection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `Client` not `client`

try like this

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { token } = process.env;
const {Client, collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
client.commands = new collection();
client.commandArray = [];

const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
  const functionFiles = fs
    .readdirSync('./src/functions/${folder}')
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of functionFiles)
    require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
}

client.handleEvents();
client.handleCommands();
client.login(token);
```

Comment: Tried this & error below now.
client.commands = new Collection();
                      ^
ReferenceError: Collection is not defined

Comment: @HyperXSpartan try `Collection` instead of `collection` on row 3

Answer (score -1):

You have initialised `client` variable twice.

```js
const {client, collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js"); // declared client here
...
...
const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds }); // also here
// const _client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds }) # this will fix with updated references of this variable
```